# How can I get my own Participant ID in a TurnBasedMatch?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I know I can obtain all Participants with TurnBasedMatch.getParticipants(), and I know I can get the player's Participant id by TurnBasedMatch.getPendingParticipantId() when it is the player's turn, but how can I get the Participant object or id if it isn't the player's turn? I could of course save it locally when it is my turn and read it later, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String myParticipantID(){
    return match.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(gac).getPlayerId());
}
```

Where `gac` is your GoogleApiClient object

Comment: This is the correct way of getting participantID, not the approved answer.

Answer (score 3):

Me and my friend developed a Chess game using this, he used java to Android and I used objective-c to iOS, he did like this to get the player:

```
Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(getApiClient())
```

then you can get the playerID or participantID through the player...

Comment: @ThomasdH How did you get the ParticipantID from a GMS.Games.Player object? If I try to call GetParticipant using that PlayerID it fails ("Participant 108961654314219883302 is not in match ChEKCQje4PTRxRoQAhACGAAgARDi1J2_9Yqbi8EB")

Comment: You can only call that in a match that is not over i guess

Comment: I get the same exception even in a uncompleted match. I believe it is probably because I am passing it a playerID, but that function wants a participantId (I think those are different).

Comment: The TurnBasedMatch object has got a method for it: [getParticipantId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html#getParticipantId(java.lang.String)). Just pass the Player Id to obtain the Participant Id.