# Google Play Games Realtime Multiplayer: How to get the participant id of the current user?

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I am developing an Android game which uses Google Play Games Realtime Multiplayer.
 I would like to determine which device is the creator/initiator of the match, so that both devices would know which device is doing all the calculations, message sending, etc.
I haven't found any documentation on this - only ways to get the creator participant id, not actually compare it to the id of the user's phone. 
 
 So essentially, I need to find a way to get the participant id of the user the code is executing on; I can handle the comparing the values from there.

Comment: you'll never know if you never try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(getApiClient())](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.html#getCurrentPlayer(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) which has been mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789318/how-can-i-get-my-own-participant-id-in-a-turnbasedmatch).

```
public String myParticipantID(){
    return match.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(gac).getPlayerId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Games.Players api to get current player id and then you can get current participant id using Room api.

```
String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(mGoogleApiClient);
String currentParticipantId = room.getParticipantId(playerId);
```

where room is [Room](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room) object and mGoogleApiClient is [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) object.